# Accessing menus in Rhythmbox on Gnome

Tags: gnome, rhythmbox

I have two machines running Ubuntu - one has Gnome Ubuntu, the other Xubuntu. Both have been recently upgraded to 14.04. On Xubuntu, Rhythmbox has both a menu and a sort of "settings" button on the upper right-hand side. On Gnome Ubuntu (since either 13.10 or 13.04) neither is visible - and, in fact, I don't know how to access the things that used to be there. For example, I don't know how to change the layout or install plugins. How do I access this functionality in Gnome?

I've attached screenshots of Rhythmbox in both desktops.

**Rhythmbox on Xubuntu**

[image: Rhythmbox of Xubuntu]

**Rhythmbox on Gnome Ubuntu**

[image: Rhythmbox on Gnome Ubuntu]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applications that confirm to the Gnome-Shell menu specification list their menus through the top panel.

[image]

This contains the menu's that you previously saw in the top-toolbar in earlier versions of Rhythmbox.

To complete the story - where you previously right-clicked playlists to see a sub-menu, these have been relocated to a source toolbar location:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To turn on or off use of the top bar to display application menus:

```
1. Install gnome-tweak-tool
2. Select the tab labeled "Top Bar"
3. Toggle "Show Application Menu".
```

An alternative is to make rhythmbox show the settings gear icon.  To do this run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '{"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu":<0>}'
```

then restart rhythmbox

Source: https://extensions.gnome.org/review/1239

Comment: The `gsettings` command worked on Ubuntu 18.04.